# Mapping values to a direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, mapping, joystick

been trying to figure this out for ages now.
Was trying to figure out a way to have my joystick when moved in any direction represent the numbers shown on the image in that direction.
I essentially I want my players movement speed to be that of the value in the direction of the stick.

[image: What I am aiming for]

I just want some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: wth are those numbers? so 1.5 is backwards 3 forwards and some gradiant along the way? so im guessing 2 is trhe middle, with some form of scale forwards all but ignoring left  or right so,  it all but looks in short, you want 2+ joystick.y , as when y is  backwards it would be -1, forwards +1, and any level in between like a rising thermometer, would be the  same per y axis.

Comment: yes 3 would be forward and 1.5 would be backwards. The values in the image can all be changed independently before run. It's the inbetween values I am having trouble getting. I have been able to get those values shown by simply doing an if statement to see which direction the stick it pointed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you have as input are

- the value 3 in "forward/up" (Y) direction (will call it `maxValue` below)
- the value 1 in "backward /down" (-Y) direction (will call it `minValue` below)
- A 2D vector user input in XY

So what you could use is a [`Vector2.Dot` product](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Dot.html) between the input and `Vector2.up` (= fully Y direction)

```
var input = new Vector2(userInputX, userInputY).normalized;
var dot = Vector2.Dot(input, Vector2.up);
```

This will be

- 1 if the input is fully aligned with the up vector
- -1 if the input is fully contrary to the up vector => fully aligned with down
- 0 if it is exactly 90° to up to aligned with left or right
- and any values in-between according to the degree of alignment

This information you can then further use as a factor in [`Mathf.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) which interpolates between two values given a factor

- 0 fully take first value
- 1 fully take second value
- anything in-between linear interpolates between first and second value

you just need to map the given range from the dot which is within `-1` and `1` onto an interpolation factor range between `0` and `1` like e.g.

```
// Remap the range -1 to 1 into the factor 0 to 1
var factor = (dot + 1f) / 2f;
var result = Mathf.Lerp(minValue, maxValue, factor);
```

---

In case also the left/right value is a given value - assuming this because your values in the graphic wouldn't match as the left/right value for 3 and 1.5 would actually be 2.25 - you can basically use the same `dot` calculation from above but then have a check in which half of the circle you are and split the interpolation into the two according parts:

```
float result;
if(dot >= 0) // dot is directly a factor 0 to 1 between left/right and up
{
    result = Mathf.Lerp(middleValue, maxValue, dot);
}
else // dot is directly a negative factor -1 to 0 between left/right and down
{
    result = Mathf.Lerp(middleValue, minValue, -dot);
}
```

---

As in the comments, indeed `Dot` is basically based on sinus so there might occur some sort of smoothing around the end values.

Alternatively you could simply go by angle and do e.g.

```
var angle = Vector2.Angle(input, Vector2.up);
float result;
if(angle <= 90)
{
    var factor = angle / 90f;
    result = Mathf.Lerp(maxValue, middleValue, factor);
}
else
{
    var factor = (angle - 90) / 90f;
    result = Mathf.Lerp(middleValue, minValue, factor);
}
```

Comment: This works great! However I am running into an issue where when the vector is aligned between the max value and middle value it is not exactly the value that it should be. 
for an example if I have 2 as the max value and 1 as the middle value then I should expect a value of 1.5 but i am receiving a value of 1.7.
I believe this to be because the dot product returns a value of .7 when pointed toward that direction.
and yes you are correct the left and right values are given just as the top and bottom values.

Comment: Hey! Possible that dot indeed is more sinus shaped .. as alternative you could simply use angles .. added this at the bottom